# Why is the order of an element of a finite group is well defined?

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group and $a\in G$, then $o(a)$ is the lowest natural number $n$ such that $a^n=e$.

How to prove that this integer exist, without arguing that $o(a)=|\langle a\rangle|$?

I know how to do it just if $G$ is cyclic.

If $G$ isn't cyclic, we have the problem that if $a\in G$, then exist some $m$ such that $a^m=b\in G$, but this $b$ isn't necessarily of the form $a^n,\; (n < m)$ or equal to $e$.

Comment: Suppose an element does not have finite order. Then it generates an infinite cyclic subgroup, but this infinite subgroup is a subset of a finite set

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the group is finite, the set $\;\{a,a^2,a^3,...\}\;$ must be finite. For the first $\;k\in\Bbb N\;$ that'd fulfill $\;a^k=a^r\;$ for some $\;r<k\;$ , we'll get $\;a^{r-k}=1\;$ ...